# Create Views with Salesforce API

Tags: rest-api, api, custom-field, list-view, custom-view

Scenario: As of now i have created a custom tab with custom fields say(name and email). The custom tab was created with the primary key to be an auto-number one {0000} and hence when the tab is loaded its default view containing only the auto-numbers is being displayed. So I have to click on each Numbered Row to view the details (name and email)

Question - How do i create a view using API that displays the name and email in the list view itself and is it possible to make this view as a default.

Please refer the below images[image]